# Javascript string equivalent on an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I am trying to parse through and delete properties that are empty. I'm having issues with javascript not equating the statement correctly.

```
var filters = { prop1 : "", prop2 : "set", prop3 : "" };
var f;
for( f in filters) {
    if(filters[f] === "") {
         delete filters[f];
    }
}
```

Using google's debug console, I know that filters[f] have given me "" for prop1 and the statement of filters[f] === "" equates to true, yet it doesn't enter inside the if statement block.

Comment: Your variable declaration says `filter` but you refer to it as `filters` later on.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, voting to close

Comment: I fixed the typo, it was my mistake when typing the question on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix the typo in your variable name, it seems to work like you expect

```
var filters = { prop1 : "", prop2 : "set", prop3 : "" };
//        ^ added
var f;
for( f in filters) {
    if(filters[f] === "") {
         delete filters[f];
    }
}
console.log(filters); // Object {prop2: "set"}
```